# Error: E0708 : E0708: Invalid transition

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop2

Using this [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/building_simple_workflows_in_oozie) i created workflow for hive script but gives me error when i run below command:

```
 oozie job -oozie http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:11000/oozie -config  /home/ec2-user/ankit/oozie_job1/job.properties -submit
```

Error which i get is this :

> Error: E0708 : E0708: Invalid transition, node [Oozie_test] transition [Tester]

My workflow code is below:

```
<workflow-app name="Tester" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="Oozie_test"/>
<action name="Oozie_test">
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
 <job-tracker>xxx.xx.xx.xx:8021</job-tracker>
 <name-node>xxx.xx.11.xx:8020</name-node>
 <configuration>
    <property>
         <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
         <value>/home/ec2-user/ankit/oozie_job1/hive-default.xml</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
 <script>hive_job1.hql</script>
</hive>
<ok to="Tester"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

As this being my first oozie workflow,i am not able to get where exactly i am going wrong or what i have missed.

I tried to  search the solution for this on internet but couldn't find any luck.

Please let me know how to solve this error and what other info is required from my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of successful execution of action (hive), transition (`ok`) is to the node `Tester`, but you do not have any node named `Tester`. That is the error.

Ideally, if you have just one action in your workflow, then successful execution of the action should go to `end`, which you have already defined in your workflow but did not use it. In case of failure you want to transit to `kill` node, which is missing in your workflow. You need to add an `kill` node and transit you hive action to it, in case of failure/error.

@charantej provided a correct workflow.

Answer (score 2):

In `ok` transition, you are referring to a node 'Tester', which doesn't exist in the workflow.

`<ok to="Tester"/>`

When any action runs successfully, it looks for the node given in **ok** transition.

Either define a new action called **'Tester'**  or give it `<ok to="end"/>`  this will go to the `end` node.

Answer (score 1):

as @YoungHobbit Explained

In case of successful execution of action (hive), transition (ok) is to the node Tester, but you do not have any node named Tester. That is the error.

Ideally, if you have just one action in your workflow, then successful execution of the action should go to end, which you have already defined in your workflow but did not use it. In case of failure you want to transit to kill node, which is missing in your workflow. You need to add an kill node and transit you hive action to it, in case of failure/error.
Try this:

```
<workflow-app name="Tester" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="Oozie_test"/>
<action name="Oozie_test">
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
 <job-tracker>xxx.xx.xx.xx:8021</job-tracker>
 <name-node>xxx.xx.11.xx:8020</name-node>
 <configuration>
    <property>
         <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
         <value>/home/ec2-user/ankit/oozie_job1/hive-default.xml</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
 <script>hive_job1.hql</script>
</hive>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: You got the correct workflow, but did not say anything what was the error in OP's workflow.

Comment: The error message looks like it's pointing to the wrong transition for some reason, but in your "Oozie_test", you have the error transition going to "fail" but you don't have a "fail" node; you probably meant "kill".

Comment: added an explanation, please check.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Thanx and you can edit my answer itself instead of Posting another answer

Comment: I have edited with your explanation. It might help anyone @YoungHobbit

Comment: When make an edit is made, that is never to add/remove the information from someone others post. It usually to correct spelling/formatting etc.

Comment: Also, whenever you copy/source the information from any other post/site, you should add a reference to them. Just an advise.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm if you have copied your workflow.xml to hdfs. You need not copy job.properties to hdfs but have to copy all the other files and libraries to hdfs