# How to load data from HDP to hive table through shell by scheduling oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I created a workflow to load data from local to hive table.
I am getting this error while running my workflow.

### Job ID : 0029058-190128212503764-oozie-oozi-W

Workflow Name : ORA_CUST_ORDER_workflow
App Path      : /user/e1721783/New_Test/Data_load_sftp_to_hdfs/oozie/ORA_CUST_ORDER_workflow.xml
Status        : KILLED
Run           : 0
User          : e1721783
Group         : -
Created       : 2019-12-03 09:24 GMT
Started       : 2019-12-03 09:24 GMT
Last Modified : 2019-12-03 09:25 GMT
Ended         : 2019-12-03 09:25 GMT
CoordAction ID: -

### Actions

### ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code

### 0029058-190128212503764-oozie-oozi-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -

### 0029058-190128212503764-oozie-oozi-W@ora_cust_order                           ERROR     job_1549028977572_283767FAILED/KILLEDJA018

### 0029058-190128212503764-oozie-oozi-W@kill                                     OK        -                      OK         E0729

Below is my workflow please check once.

$ oozie job -oozie http://tcldighdpmdev01:11000/oozie -config /home/e1721783/Data_load_sftp_to_hdfs/oozie/job.properties -run
Error: E0708 : E0708: Invalid transition, node [ora_cust_order] transition [kill]

```
    <action name="ora_cust_order">
   <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                    <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>${EXEC}</exec>
        <!--<env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=e1721783</env-var>-->
        <file>/user/e1721783/New_Test/Data_load_sftp_to_hdfs/job/Load_sftp_to_hive.sh#Load_sftp_to_hive.sh</file>
            </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
```

Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]

Comment: You are referring to a nodes named 'kill' and 'end' ```( <ok to="end"/> <error to="kill"/>``` ). Are they defined at the end of your workflow?

Comment: Side note: a "shell" action would require a property in the form `oozie.launcher.*` (in V4.x, not sure about V5 given the enormous amount of refactoring)

Comment: What is the point of using a parameter for `<exec>` since the same exact script name (I guess) is hard-coded in `<file>`??

Comment: What is the return code of your script? Non-zero will be interpreted as "error" hence the branching to `kill`...

Comment: @– Tsvetelina Mariyanova: yes that is  ( <ok to=" end"/> <error to="kill"/> )  used at the end of workflow....could you please suggest what would be the right way to define that end and kill .

Comment: Hi, Samson <Exec> is the script that will load the file from the HDP landing zone to the HIve table. That's why I am passing that one ..would you please suggest me how to load a text file from HDP to hive table. script what will pick the file from /home/Subrat/file_loaction to hive table . and that will schedule by Oozie work flow .

Comment: @Smson: for example if my file would be the in-home directory of HDP i.e home/Surat/data/t1.txt and I want to load this t1.txt file into hive table .please give me idea any sample script with oozie workflow XML file.

Comment: I believe same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726711/7857701